# Update MYSQL and SET particular row Content

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to update my table t1 which has rows as following :-

1. id
2. menu

Currently i am having data in it as

```
id = "1"  
menu = "menu1 ,menu2 ,menu3, menu4"
```

I am using explode method of PHP to get MENU row of my table t1.

```
$show_data = mysql_query("SELECT menu FROM t1");
$showrow  = mysql_fetch_assoc($show_data);
$showmenu =  $showrow['menu'];
$pieces = explode(",", $showmenu);
```

Now I want to delete content **menu3** from row **MENU** , 
  Please provide me which query should i use , UPDATE , ALTER or DELETE.

Comment: You should [normalize](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) that table schema, because the way you have it is not even in the [1NF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form).

Comment: Are the contents of the menu `menu1 ,menu2 ,menu3, menu4`, `menu1, menu2, menu3, menu4`, or `menu1,menu2,menu3,menu4`?

Comment: Read the documentation for each one and pick the one that suits.

Comment: Never ever use csv in a database it will bite you again and again and again

Comment: Shef , Its Like this :- 
menu1 ,menu2 ,menu3, menu4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is better to separate `$menu1 $manu2 $menu3` and `$menu4`

1. You can `implode()` them as a single `$string` with `\t` separator
2. and `Insert` it to Mysql.
3. When nessesary,`select` the field from table
4. `explode()` it to separate strings using `\t` separator
5. remove the `$menu3` variable frome being imploded this time
6. again `implode()` them
7. and `UPDATE` the field

Answer (score 2):

You should store your menus in a **separate table**, linked to this one by a unique identifier.

Then edit that table in the usual way.